# Change in OCR Result?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I'm now seeing the full text found in the image in the first "textAnnotation" value, and then each word again in a new textAnnotation (so effectively everything is duplicated).  I wasn't seeing this behavior just a couple days ago, so I assume this is an intentional change.  Does anyone know if I can just rely on the first textAnnotatation as being the full result?  Thanks.

Comment: I got the same results.

Comment: I got the same results.

More than one textAnnotations are in the response. The second textAnnotation and its after are every single word or short words of the first one.

I think this is good because I can get more information about boundingPoly corresponding to every word.

Comment: I agree it is good, I was just having trouble finding any explicit documentation of the change, and whether I could rely on the first annotation being the full text.